# How do I serve the static "next export" output directory from a next.js app?

Tags: webpack, dynamic, next.js, static, netlify

I followed the docs to convert my next.js app to a static app. I want my next.js app to be static so I can deploy it with Netlify Sites instead of paying for a dynamic app server on Digital Ocean, AWS, etc... or something like that.

My example/test app has no db calls or anything that would make it challenging to convert to a static app, it basically just a boilerplate for testing purposes: https://github.com/ChristianOConnor/lit-protocol-nextjs-turbopack-fix. You can reproduce my steps by cloning the app, running `npm install` and then `npm run build`. my build script in the `package.json` file is `next build && next export`. After running `npm run build`, `cd` into the `out` directory that was created with the build command, and run `python -m http.server` to server the directory.

The problem becomes apparent when you navigate to `localhost:8000` in the browser. This is what it looks like:
[image]

As you can see, the python webserver is just serving the directory, and the next.js app isn't loading/working. When I run the app with `npm run dev`, the app looks like this:
[image]

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't seem to have an `index.html` file in the `out` folder. That should've been generated when running `next export`. Also, the GitHub repo you shared is not accessible.